# Can't find "Create solution settings" menu option

Tags: visual-studio-2013, web-essentials

I'm trying to create solution specific settings using the Web Essentials VS extension. On the [features page](http://vswebessentials.com/features/general) for Web Essentials it states:

> To enable solution settings, right-click any item in Solution Explorer
>   and click "Create solution settings".

I can't find that option anywhere. I'm using VS 2013 Update 2 and Web Essentials 2013 for Update 2.

[image]

What am I missing? Where should I be looking to find the option to create solution specific settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find it in the menubar, not in the contextual menu.

See https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2013/issues/331#issuecomment-32735084 or [image: https://camo.githubusercontent.com/71219f1fb66d97fe87cef806b46a1c2dd6f6bcb7/68747470733a2f2f662e636c6f75642e6769746875622e636f6d2f6173736574732f3531353935352f313935313837312f66386236613032342d383139332d313165332d383636652d6365343935633435363161372e706e67]